# How to clean up a project - remove unused materials

Tags: edit-mode

I have a project which has become quite messy with some materials which are duplicates eg material names have suffixes of .001, .002 etc which I have worked out how to fix HOWEVER some materials which are orphans which I want to remove.

I found a tutorial which advises to use PURGE ('button in Blender 2.8) but I cannot find that in Blender 3.1

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Outliner* window which in the default layout sits at the top right has different display modes. Default is *View Layer* where you see all your scene objects, but if you click there to open the dropdown menu, there is *Orphan Data*. Select it and then you will find the *Purge* button.

[image: purge button]

If you don't want to get rid of everything, instead of using the *Purge* button you could also select certain orphan datablocks, then right-click and choose *Delete*.

To get rid of unused datablocks you can also do the following: go to the main menu, *File* > *Clean Up* and either choose *Unused Data-Blocks* or *Recursive Unused Data-Blocks* (I usually take the "recursive" because I sometimes get the impression otherwise some orphans still remain).

[image: clear unused datablocks]

Comment: Thanks. Gordon.  I did 'open' the Help>Menu but didn't see it there. I didn't even see the 'cleanup' option maybe because I was trying to locate it using what I saw in the 2.8 tutorial.

Comment: @JohnArnold You're welcome. I've edited my answer to add another possible way of removing orphans.

Comment: That begs another question which is something I have cleaned up but just wondered if there is any advantage in doing this. And that is when the same material assignments have different 'names' (as during the learning process I failed to assign the same name to multiple meshes). For example the original material name might be material.red and there also are material.red.001, material.red.002 etc. Is there a benefit in reassigning so that they all are material.red?

Comment: Unused material blocks should get purged when you save and reopen a file anyway unless you've marked them as having a fake user.

Comment: @JohnArnold I'm not sure what you mean "failed to assign the same name". When you have multiple objects, materials or whatever, it is not possible to assign the same name to the same types of objects. For example, if you create a mesh object called "Sphere", you cannot give another object the name "Sphere", it will automatically be renamed to "Sphere.001". Until you manually delete the ".001", then Blender renames the original "Sphere" to "Sphere.001". It is possible though to name a material "Sphere" to indicate it is the sphere's material. But a new material will get the ".001" as well.

Comment: @JohnArnold If you want the exact same material e.g. "material.red" on each object but have accidentally created multiple materials, then the benefit of reassigning is of course that you don't have multiple materials where one is sufficient. Also changing something will automatically have all objects use the changed material instead of having to change them on all objects separately. The other thing is, when you duplicate a material to create a new different one, Blender automatically uses the old name and adds ".001" - but nonetheless you can make "material.red.001" blue instead of red ;)

Comment: Yes on thinking about it an advantage of using the same material name (on various different meshes) would be that if a change is required (eg change the roughness or specular value then it changes all of them rather than having  to change every different one. Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnArnold Although you are still phrasing it a bit misunderstandably. Using the same material name sounds as if you are trying to use the name itself multiple times, but you're not. The name is unique and given to only one material. And this material can be used on different meshes. Sorry to be nit-picky on this, I'm sure you have understood my point - it's just for future questions here helpful to get the terms correct. If you say something like you "want to use the same name on different stuff", people will tell you it's not possible to have the same name on more than one thing.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I tried to explain it by using the material name (example) material.red and material.red.001 etc which could have been different colors as you point out. I should have used my original material name of material.concrete.tiles.rotated 
(from a texture file I created) but wanted a shorter name for the example - sorry for the confusion.